# Java Logback + System.Logger? Logback java.lang.System.LoggerFinder implementation?

Tags: java, logback

Does the Logback library support or provide a bridge for the Java 9+ logging facade, `System.Logger`? I want something analogous to Log4j's `log4j-jpl` which lets you use Log4j as a logging backend or implementation.

Comment: No, SLF4J does however (which is the API used by Logback). See https://www.slf4j.org/manual.html#jep264

Comment: @M.Deinum I'm guessing that clay wants an appender only. By using that SLF4J binding you won't be able to log to both files and `System.Logger`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you? That binds to `System.Logger` and eventually delegates to logback which you can configure in anywhich way you want.

Answer (score 0):

System.Logger uses the LoggerFinder class to find System.Logger implementations, which SLF4J (what logback uses) provides in the slf4j-jdk-platform-logging folder of the slf4j repository (https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/tree/master/slf4j-jdk-platform-logging). If you're stuck on 1.7.x, I found this: https://github.com/avaje/slf4j-jdk-platform-logging. (You can easily write your own LoggerFinder implemenation if all else fails.)